# GStreamer 1.19 error: gst/sdp/sdp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, compiling, gstreamer

Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 --gst-version
GStreamer Core Library version 1.19.0.1
```

My helloworld program has these includes:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gst/sdp/sdp.h>
```

Compiling it as follows:

```
$ gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0)
helloworld.c:3:10: fatal error: gst/sdp/sdp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gst/sdp/sdp.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I followed this: https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2020/03/19/getting-started-with-gstreamer-gst-build/

```
$ locate gst/sdp
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/builddir/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/builddir/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/builddir/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/libgstsdp-1.0.so
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/builddir/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/libgstsdp-1.0.so.0
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp/gstsdpdemux.c
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp/gstsdpdemux.h
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp/gstsdpelem.c
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp/gstsdpsrc.c
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp/gstsdpsrc.h
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/sdp/meson.build
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/gstmikey.c
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/gstmikey.h
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/gstsdp.h
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/gstsdpmessage.c
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/gstsdpmessage.h
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/meson.build
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/sdp-prelude.h
/home/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/sdp/sdp.h
```

Tried to run it:

```
$ GST_DEBUG=videotestsrc:1 gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=1 ! fakevideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.033698197
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Installed `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`

```
$sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
$locate gst/sdp  
...
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/sdp
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/sdp/gstmikey.h
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/sdp/gstsdp.h
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/sdp/gstsdpmessage.h
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/sdp/sdp-prelude.h
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/sdp/sdp.h
[gst-master] xyz:~/.../work/gstreamer-setup/gst-build$ gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0)
helloworld.c:3:10: fatal error: gst/sdp/sdp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gst/sdp/sdp.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What information should I present here for you to help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gst%2Fsdp%2Fsdp.h) you have to install single package by the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

Also I would highly recommend to use all GST packages from the [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/gst-plugins-base1.0).

Comment: I installed libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev. Please see the update to the question and tell what needs to be done next.